# how to get hasmany relation inside another relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

how to get hasmany relation inside another relation in Laravel

i want to get product optionGroup with product options

i made this

```
    $try1 = Product::with(["optionGroups.options"])->find(1);
```

but this return all group options

i want to get product optionGroup with product options only

i want it to be like

```
{
  "title": "product name",
  "optionGroups": [
    {
      "name": "Size",
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "XL",
          "price": 1200
        },
        {
          "name": "L",
          "price": 1000
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**models**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class, 'product_id');
    }
    public function optionGroups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OptionGroup::class, 'options')->groupBy("id");
    }
}

class Option extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
    public function optionGroup()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\OptionGroup::class, 'option_group_id', 'id');
    }
}

class OptionGroup extends Model
{
    public $table = 'option_groups';
    public $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class, 'option_group_id');
    }
}

Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    $table->string('title');
});
Schema::create('options', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 127);
    $table->double('price', 8, 2)->default(0);
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('option_group_id')->unsigned();
});
Schema::create('option_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 127);
});
```

please help me

Comment: Have you tried? `Product::with(["options.optionGroup"])->find(1);`

Comment: Yes but this will return the group inside the option

Comment: I want the option inside the group

Comment: Have you looked at the hasManyThrough relation?

Answer (score 2):

```
Product::whereHas('optionGroups', function($query){
     $query->with(['options']);
})->first();
```

Comment: This will return the group inside the option ....  i want the  option inside the group 

Comment: @yemenpoint I just updated the answer . Once try that and let me know

Comment: Hi Bipin this doesn't return any option or any optionGroup

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Product model

```
public function optionGroupsAndOptions()
{
    return $this->optionGroups->with('options')->where('product_id', $this->id);
}
```

then

```
$try1 = Product::with("optionGroupsAndOptions")->find(1);
```

Comment: Not work i even tried this.    return $this->optionGroups()->with(["options" => function($q){
      $q->where("product_id",$this->id);
    }]);

Comment: $this->id is null and this["id"] is null

Comment: Try this `$try1 = Product::with("optionGroupsAndOptions")->where('product_id', 1);`